WYSIWYG CRM solution for easy Database visualization
I have been aggregating data on acquisitions of small companies in Europe that are currently being sold or have been sold for a while. After numerous requests, I would like to make this data available to the public at no cost, while continuing to update it.
I am currently considering what the best low-maintenance WYSIWYG CRM solution would be.
It needs to allow for:

Easy updates
Efficient filtering
Email notifications based on a set of filters
Links to pages with more detail

It needs to be a solution that works straight out of the box. Thx!

This doesn't sound like a use-case for a Customer Relationship Management (CRM) system. Especially if (big assumption) your starting point is a bespoke database.
You need to first identify the answers to a few questions:

Do you want to host something yourself, or do you need a managed SaaS solution? This will depend on your need for customisation and your experience in deploying websites / apps to the cloud.

Do you have any development experience, or does this need to be a totally off-the-shelf solution requiring no coding experience?

Is your data already implemented in a database engine (MySQL etc?) or is your data unstructured/semi-structured, i.e. in the form of spreadsheets and other documents.


Once you've answered those, some initial thoughts/suggestions.
Assuming a level of development / coding experiance: My first thought when reading your use-case was something like Grafana, which is a data visualisation tool with out-of-the-box connectors for databases such as MySQL, MongoDB, many others.
But given your list of required features, you might need some form of bespoke application that integrates data visualisations from Grafana. I am not aware of something off-the-shelf that offers data visualisation on a custom data model / database, as well as email notifications and content pages with further detail.
There are app development frameworks which could give you a major head start though. Python Django has an ORM that makes working with existing MySQL databases pretty quick, and you could embed Grafana visualisations in the application views.
There are also low / no-code web app development tools such as Retool, that can connect to your database, and offer a drag-and-drop experience for building a custom web application.
Alternatively, assuming you have less development experience and do not already have a database set up: if I've misunderstood and you don't have a database schema already, you just have collated your research in a spreadsheet / other documents, you could set up a website with Wordpress or another off-the-shelf website publishing tool, and manually create a page for each of the companies you have researched.
